# Singularity of $\frac{1 - e^{-z}}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I think the function $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb C,\ z\mapsto \frac{1 - e^{-z}}{z}$ has removable singularity at 0. Since lim of the function is 1 (By L-Hospital Rule)
Since the limit is finite, so we can redefine the function, so that it has no singularity..
Am I Correct? Or please Help..

Comment: It is correct that $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to0} f(z)=1$ and hence $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. However, it is not because of the L'Hôpital's rule in real analysis.

Comment: @SangchulLee The Hôpital rule can also be applied in complex analysis, can it not? At least in the case of $0/0$ and $z\to\alpha\in\mathbb C$. Even if one may here also just say that the limit is equal to the derivative of $-e^{-z}$ at $z=0$ by definition.

Comment: @Zuy, Although the statement of L'Hôpital's rule continues to hold (with due modification) in complex analysis, it is based on rather different mechanism (i.e., the properties of zeros/poles of meromorphic functions) compared to that of the original, real-analysis version (i.e., mean-value theorem). I don't think people actually call this "L'Hôpital's rule".

Comment: @Sangchul Lee thanks